# Unable to upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

After issuing:

```
update-manager
```

And then clicking "Upgrade..." in Software Updater the terminal displays "Checking for a new Ubuntu release" but does not show the dialog to proceed.  Which means I am unable to upgrade.  PS -UX shows:

```
trevor    4406  1.8  0.0   4444   800 pts/3    S+   11:45   0:03 /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/pkexec /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade --frontend=DistUpgradeViewGtk3
```

Any suggestions?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 in a VMWARE virtual machine on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're lucky if you can even update a current install - I haven't been able to run the security updates on mine for a few days now, timeout/connection problem on two internet connections.

Apparently the 15.04 is too popular right now :) If you go to Settings... in the upgrade dialog, and in Software-sources set the server to Main Server or a server near you, it may work better.

Comment: I've just updated on another computer and it worked perfectly.  I don't think it is a time out issue.

Comment: What server is your software-sources set to? What geographical area are you downloading from?

Comment: ubuntu.mirror.serversaustralia.com.au

Comment: thanks for the solution - it was to switch to the main ubuntu server.  If you edit your answer I'll accept.

Comment: @TrevTheDev That is not the solution, I can't even get security updates on my 14.04 - from Main Server, or United States server. It's been this way for days.

Comment: it work for me!?

Comment: Ok, looks like the problem I was having was due to installing Cyberduck, their repo somehow broke apt-get upgrade (which I didn't know was possible) - https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/8788